# OAuth 401 "access_denied" from Patreon API

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, patreon

I'm really stumped on this one, so any help or pointers would be most welcome. I'm following this documentation:

https://www.patreon.com/platform/documentation/oauth

I ran through all the necessary calls in Postman and have got access to the API. Then when I tried to run it through a Node.js / Express app and I started to get the following response as soon as I used the single use token (Step 3 in the referred documentation):

```
{
  "error": "access_denied"
}
```

I then took the single use code that was being sent to my app and pasted it into the params in Postman and I got the same result (a 401 error). Only when I changed the redirect_url to a php script (on a remote server) and then used that single use code with postman did I get a 200 response.

The following ...

```
www.patreon.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=###&redirect_uri=http://www.somesite.com/script.php
```

... gives me a working code and ...

```
www.patreon.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=#####&redirect_uri=http://localhost.com
```

goves me a code that doesn't work.

I am making both the subsequent calls for the oauth token from Postman so I am a bit lost as to why this is happening.

I am very new to Node.js and Express but I have worked with oauth and api's in general for some time.

Things I have tried:

- Using a url shortner for the redirect url
- using dotted quad instead of localhost

Thanks in advance,

roscminni

EDIT:

Here is the node code that is receiving the redirect

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/valid').get(function(req, res){

    console.log("CODE");
    console.log(req.query.code);
    res.redirect("http://google.com");

});
```

And here's the app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var valid = require('./routes/valid');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/valid',valid);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can you post your node code?

Comment: Just added the node code - I am pretty novice at Node but trying to learn fast. Note that all I am doing is copying the code from the terminal and then running via postman at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue was that the redirect_url argument had to be the same in all the API calls.

So I was calling:

```
1st call: /oauth/?redirect_url=http://foo.foo/bar
Next call: /oauth/?redirect_url=http://foo.foo/foo
```

But I needed to do this:

```
1st call: /oauth/?redirect_url=http://foo.foo/bar
Next call: /oauth/?redirect_url=http://foo.foo/bar
```

It appears that the redirect has to be exactly the same on all the oauth calls in the patreon API need to have the same redirect_url.